# Count the average issue sql

Tags: mysql, sql, count, average

I have a table with workers and their salary.
I try to count how many workers have salary bigger than the average
I know how to show the average, I know how to count how many workers the company have
but I failed to answer the question. This what I tried but I get an error:

```
SELECT COUNT(workers_id) FROM flight_company.workers
WHERE Salary > AVG(Salary);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, use window functions:

```
select avg_salary, count(*) no_workers_above_average
from (select salary, avg(salary) over() avg_salary from flight_company.workers) t
where salary > avg_salary
group by avg_salary
```

In earlier versions, one option is a join with an aggregate query:

```
select a.avg_salary, count(*) no_workers_above_average
from flight_company.workers w
inner join (select avg(salary) avg_salary from flight_company.workers) a
where w.salary > a.avg_salary
group by a.avg_salary
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery :

```
select count(w.workers_id))
from flight_company.workers w
where salary > (select avg(salary) from flight_company.workers);
```

Comment: @user13269342 . . . This is equivalent to your answer, and you should accept this (or one of the other) answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with window function `avg()` (MySql 8.0+) and aggregation:

```
select sum(t.flag)
from (select salary > avg(salary) over () flag from workers) t
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me

`SELECT COUNT(workers_id) as Num_Above_Average FROM flight_company.workersWHERE Salary > (select avg(salary) from flight_company.workers)`

how do i add the average salary colume to this?

thanks

Comment: Just look at GMB's answer.